# Unshift data to array in Redux reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, react-redux

On the dispatch of the `UPDATE_DATA` action, I am able to push data to my `state.data` array in the reducer with the following code.

```
const toPush = {
    name : "Pushed Name",
    id_name : 100,
    more1 : "pushedMore01"
}

case "UPDATE_DATA":
  return {
    ...state,
    data: [...state.data, toPush],
    isFetching: false
}
```

How do I unshift rather than push the data to state? What would be clean ES6 syntax for the same?

Comment: `[toPush, ...state.data]` didn't work ?

Comment: do you just want to place the new object in the start of the array or update an existing object in the array?

Comment: For now just to place the new object in the start of the array.

Comment: then you already got an answer by Andrew Li & Vivic

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just switch the order:

```
data: [toPush, ...state.data]
```

This will insert the new item at the beginning, then spread the rest of the previous data after it.